# Creating Photoshop Plugin - trying to find simpler way to source file in javascript function

Tags: javascript, photoshop

I'm creating a plugin I would like to be used for both Mac and Windows.

As the file trees are different, I would like to find a simpler way to source a file in a function contained in my /host/index.jsx file.

My file is located at /files/thisismyfile.psd

Currently I can only successfully source it by entering the full file tree from the main hard drive:

```
var fileRef = new File("/Library/Application Support/Adobe/CEP/extensions/com.my.panel/files/thisismyfile.psd");
```

I would much prefer to use something like:

```
var fileRef = new File("./files/thisismyfile.psd");
```

I've also tried testing having the file in each other folder and simply searching for:

```
var fileRef = new File("thisismyfile.psd");
```

With no luck! Any ideas?

Failing that, is it possible to code it so that it says:

"If this is mac, then search for the file here. If this is windows, then search for the file here."?

Comment: Hi Josef, I'm not quite understanding your question, maybe you can clarify... **1.** Are you wanting to provide a path to a file (i.e. `"./files/thisismyfile.psd"`) which is relative to where `index.jsx` is stored? **2.** Am I correct in thinking that the issue is that the location of `index.jsx` differs between Win and Mac? **3.** What's the full absolute path to the `/host/index.jsx` ? and how does that relate to `"/Library/Application Support/Adobe/CEP/extensions/com.my.panel"` ?

Comment: @RobC 

Hi there, thanks for your reply!

1. Yes, ideally I'd like to try and find a path relative to index.jsx without having to list the full absolute path.
2. Yes, that's the main issue, as the alternative would be to have two releases for users of Win and Mac just for the sake of one line of coding.
3. The full absolute path to index.jsx on Mac is:
`/Library/Application Support/Adobe/CEP/extensions/com.my.panel/host/index.jsx`

Just as a note, I've also tried using `../files/thisismyfile.psd`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this script to determine the location of the file depending on whether the system being used is mac or windows.

```
function isMacOS() {
  return ($.os.toLowerCase().indexOf('mac') >= 0);
}
var fileRef = isMacOS()
    ? new File("/Library/Application Support/Adobe/CEP/extensions/my.panel/files/filename.psd")
    : new File("C:\Program Files\Common Files\Adobe\CEP\extensions\my.panel\files\filename.psd");

    var docRef = app.open(fileRef);
  };
```